# (WPF/C#) Binding to an object inside a method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my quest to understand DataContext and bindings better, I have tried to make an example where a TextBlock displays a property of an object, where the property value is decided by a DispatcherTimer. However, the TextBlock will not display any values.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SfGauge.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding myObj, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RandomVal}">
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    randomValue myObj = new randomValue();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer aTimer;
        aTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        aTimer.Interval += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        aTimer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

        aTimer.Start();


    }
 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {

                myObj.giveRandom();
            });   
       }

}
public class randomValue : ObservableObject
{
    Random r = new Random();
    private int randomval;
    public int RandomVal { get
        {
            return randomval;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref randomval, value);
        }
   }
    public void giveRandom()
    {
        RandomVal = r.Next(0, 100);
    }
    public randomValue()
    {
        RandomVal = 0;
    }
}
```

ObservableObject.cs

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
 
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value)) return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` of an element is basically just an object. The default value of `DataContext` is the `DataContext` of the element's parent, e.g.:

```
myTextBlock.DataContext = myTextBloc.Parent.DataContext
```

This isn't "correct", but it illustrates how the `DataContext` trickles down. This goes all the way to the top element (which is `Window` in this case). The `Window`'s `DataContext` defaults to `null`.

When you're trying to bind the `DataContext` of `Grid` the `Binding` uses the `DataContext` of the `Grid` to find the property `myObj`. The `DataContext` of `Grid` is `Window.DataContext` which is `null` which will make the `Binding` not work.

To be able to bind to properties on the `Window` itself, you'll have to set the `Window` as the `DataContext` of itself:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.DataContext = this;

    ...
}
```

Additionally: you can only bind to properties, so you'll have to make `myObj` a property:

```
public randomValue myObj { get; set; } = new randomValue()
```

Doing this should make you bindings work as you expect.

Alternatively you could do as @mm8 suggests and set the `DataContext` of the `TextBlock` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the intuitive answer! Would +1 if I could :)

Comment: As an aside, I can see this only works if the property randomValue is public. The Timer method can still access it though, so it seems like the only thing it impacts is the binding. Can bindings only access public properties?

Comment: As a general rule yes. this is a special case however: since the XAML and code-behind technically is the same class, the `Binding` has access to private properties.

Comment: "Binding has access to private properties" is wrong. WPF data binding only works with public properties, regardless of where they are declared.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DataContext` to `myObj` programmatically:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = myObj; //<--

    DispatcherTimer aTimer;
    aTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    aTimer.Interval += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    aTimer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    aTimer.Start();
}
```

This won't work:

```
DataContext="{Binding myObj, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

You can only bind to public properties. If you define `myObj` as a public property of your window class, you could also bind to it like this in your XAML markup:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding myObj, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
```